# AWS Device Farm: issue launching iOS app with argument through Calabash

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, calabash, aws-device-farm

I am using Calabash to run test for my iOS app in AWS Device Farm. I need to launch app with argument. I added below code in features/support/01_launch.rb

```
Before do |scenario|
    launcher = Calabash::Launcher.launcher
    options = {
        :args => ['someargument']
    }
    launcher.relaunch(options)
    launcher.calabash_notify(self)
end
```

Locally it is able to launch app with argument 'someargument' and then proceed with test.
But in AWS Device farm it is not passing argument. App launches without argument and then test runs.
Is this feature not supported in AWS Device Farm or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.
The functionality you are looking at is passing in arguments to calabash test through device farm.

If you look closely at the Device Farm console you will notice that you can upload profile which is a .yaml configuration file. You can pass in your arguments in here and that should be picked up by your tests.

Let me know if you run in to any issues with using it.

**Update:**

The official documentation is currently being updated but we do support profiles in calabash

**Update 2**

Based on the users exact description and clarification from jmoody (Thank you!) if you were looking for passing an argument to the application through the launcher that is not possible today but is certainly that can be looked at based on user feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But in the aws doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-ios-calabash.html , it says profile is not supported.

"Device Farm currently does not support Calabash configuration profiles or tags." And I also don't see a way to upload profile.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the fact that the documentation is currently being updated but we do support profiles. Sorry about the inconvenience this may have caused

Comment: Few more qq. I can upload zipped features folder. But where can i upload .yml file. Also I still don't know how using profile will solve my problem. Currently I am using hardcoded value to pass argument and it is not working.  

And even if I use profile I will still need to pass argument in the same block of code in launch.rb file.

Comment: Hi NikofTime, if you guys plan to support the feature then do you know when will it be possibly available?  One more question, could you let me know how can I pass profile to DeviceFarm through Jenkins. In Jenkins I can only pass Tags, there is no way to pass profile.

Answer (score 0):

> You can pass in your arguments in here and that should be picked up by your tests.

The :args option in Launcher#relaunch represent arguments that are passed to the application at launch.  These are not environment variables to control the behavior of Calabash or options for cucumber.  I don't think it is possible to set application runtime arguments from a cucumber configuration file - unless, of course, Amazon is doing something under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification !